# How to fill a specific position missing value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, fillna

I have a [pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcFWu.png) with 15 x 15 dimensions.

I am trying to fill the missing values using if statement. I want to fill the mirrored position of filled values. For example, `if z.values[0, 0] == 1` then I want to fill the `z.values[15, 15]` value equal to 0 and vise versa.
I am using this code:

```
    if z.values[0, 0] == 1:
        z.values[15, 15].fillna() == 0
    else:
        z.values[15, 15].fillna() == 1
```

Note: This is just for `z.values[0, 0]` I also want all the indexing to have the above mentioned coding using a for loop or something else.

Comment: Can you please specify how to mirror each position? I've added my answer but I'm not sure if the output matches your expectations (since your example only explains diagonals)

Comment: Like if there is 1 at position [0,0], I want to fill the position at [15,15] equal to 0. Similarly, if there is 0 at position [0,1], I want 1 at [15,14] and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first invert your dataframe by reversing the index and columns:

```
>>> df2 = df.loc[df.index[::-1], df.columns[::-1]]
```

Then, we replace 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s:

```
>>> df2 = df2.replace({0: 1, 1: 0})
```

Now, use those values to fill your datafrme only where the value is currently null:

```
>>> df[df.isnull()] = df2.values
```

For example, for this sample input:

```
    F4   F3   F2   F1
F4   1  1.0  1.0  1.0
F3   0  1.0  1.0  NaN
F2   1  1.0  NaN  NaN
F1   1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The output is this:

```
    F4   F3   F2   F1
F4   1  1.0  1.0  1.0
F3   0  1.0  1.0  0.0
F2   1  1.0  0.0  1.0
F1   1  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. May be I need to clearly define you what I want. Like if there is 1 at position [0,0], I want to fill the position at [15,15] equal to 0. Similarly, if there is 0 at position [0,1], I want 1 at [15,14] and so on.

Comment: @Zaman I've updated my answer by using `df.replace` to replace the values in `df2` (the new values)